# Django - admin add textarea list

Tags: python, django

I want to customize django admin "add" page. It should display only empty textarea where you can add "a list" of keywords. Each new line representing new object.

Just for example:

```
class KW(models.Model):
    KWuser = models.CharField('Keyword', max_length=1000)
```

And if someone entered:

```
one
two
three
5656
aa
```

It would create 5 objects for KW model. Can't find if anything like this already exists, if not please point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Why not use `TextField` instead? I don't think it's a good practice to use a `CharField` for holding more than 255 characters whereas you're using 1000!

Comment: They would all be saved as different KW models no same one.

Comment: Have you considered using something like django-taggit? http://django-tagging.readthedocs.org/en/develop/